# Is there a certain method of sending links within HTML emails, to show them "inline"?

Tags: c#, html, email

In my web app, I send HTML emails to members, which contain links. Pretty standard stuff. However, I was chatting with one of my users who mentioned the links appear beside the link text. Something like this:

> Hi user, click here to check this out < http://www.checkthisout.com >.

Instead of appearing like:

> Hi user, [click here to check this out](http://www.checkthisout.com).

Yet, the user claims they do receive the latter from other sources (though, my Gmail account formated the links like the second example). Is there a certain way links must be embedded for them to more reliably be linked as in the latter example?

(note: I'm using .Net/C# to send messages.)

Comment: this is done at the email client level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many email client will actually do this automatically. I know the one I use at work tends to pull the url out of the link and place it to the side. Annoying I know but you can't control everything, so you have to just deal with things as such.

Comment: Cool, that's what I suspected... asked just in case. ;)

Comment: Yeah. It's better to ask then to bang your head trying to fix something that you may not have control over. :D